# Woocommerce do not apply coupon if subtotal below minimum amount

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have issue.
I have coupon that give me 15% off.
Also i have shipping method that works on minimum $200.
I noticed if I apply coupon on amount ~ $200, subtotal goes under $200 and coupon shipping method worked.
I am wondering to create a way to restrict smarter coupon to not be applied if subtotal goes below $200.

Code I am trying is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' , 'home_test_coupon_fix' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form' , 'home_test_coupon_fix' );
function home_test_coupon_fix() {
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->get_subtotal();
    $coupon_id = 'hometest';
    $minimum_amount = 200 + WC()->cart->get_coupon_discount_amount( 'hometest' );
    $currency_code = get_woocommerce_currency();
    wc_clear_notices();
    
    echo $minimum_amount;

    if ( $cart_total < $minimum_amount && $woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons === $coupon_id ) {
         WC()->cart->remove_coupon( 'hometest' );
         wc_print_notice( "Get 50% off if you spend more than $minimum_amount $currency_code!", 'notice' );
    } 
    wc_clear_notices();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some bugs in your code. first, you not declare `global $woocommerce;` into starting of your function. `$woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons` this will be array so you have to pass key to check `hometest`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' , 'home_test_coupon_fix' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form' , 'home_test_coupon_fix' );

function home_test_coupon_fix() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $cart_total     = WC()->cart->get_subtotal();
    $coupon_id      = 'hometest';
    $minimum_amount = 500 + WC()->cart->get_coupon_discount_amount( $coupon_id );
    $currency_code  = get_woocommerce_currency();
    wc_clear_notices();
    if ( $cart_total < $minimum_amount && $woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons[0] === $coupon_id ) {
        WC()->cart->remove_coupon( 'hometest' );
        wc_print_notice( "Get 50% off if you spend more than $minimum_amount $currency_code!", 'notice' );
    } 
    wc_clear_notices();
}
```

**Updated as per OP request**

You can use the `woocommerce_coupon_message` filter hook to remove the coupon message.

```
function remove_coupon_message( $msg, $msg_code, $this ){
    global $woocommerce;
    $cart_total     = WC()->cart->get_subtotal();
    $coupon_id      = 'hometest';
    $minimum_amount = 500 + WC()->cart->get_coupon_discount_amount( $coupon_id );
    $currency_code  = get_woocommerce_currency();
    wc_clear_notices();
    if ( $cart_total <= $minimum_amount && $woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons[0] === $coupon_id ) {
        return "";  
    }
    return $msg;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_coupon_message','remove_coupon_message', 10,3 );
```

**Tested and works.**

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Bhautik.
Your solution worked beatifully!
Only have bug with "Coupon apply message", that i cannot clear.
See here: 
[link](https://prnt.sc/11vj8kw)

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly. One last question: If i want to make for all coupons, not for single, what should change in condition?

Comment: Thanks, but what about WC() ->cart->remove_coupon(), will this remove coupon or should be given value inside ()

Comment: Check my answer here [Woocommerce do not apply coupon if amount go below certain amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67286414/woocommerce-do-not-apply-coupon-if-amount-go-below-certain-amount)