# Woocommerce do not apply coupon if amount go below certain amount

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Thanks to @Bhautik I have solution to not apply coupon if cart amount goes below certain amount.
My topic is:
*I have issue. I have coupon that give me 15% off. Also i have shipping method that works on minimum $200. I noticed if I apply coupon on amount ~ $200, subtotal goes under $200 and coupon shipping method worked. I am wondering to create a way to restrict smarter coupon to not be applied if subtotal goes below $200.*
I want to remove restriction from single coupon code and be anyone.

Solution we have

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' , 'home_test_coupon_fix' );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form' , 'home_test_coupon_fix' );
    
    function home_test_coupon_fix() {
        global $woocommerce;
        $cart_total     = WC()->cart->get_subtotal();
        $coupon_id      = 'hometest';
        $minimum_amount = 500 + WC()->cart->get_coupon_discount_amount( $coupon_id );
        $currency_code  = get_woocommerce_currency();
        wc_clear_notices();
        if ( $cart_total < $minimum_amount && $woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons[0] === $coupon_id ) {
            WC()->cart->remove_coupon( 'hometest' );
            wc_print_notice( "Get 50% off if you spend more than $minimum_amount $currency_code!", 'notice' );
        } 
        wc_clear_notices();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this `&& $woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons[0] === $coupon_id` conditions for apply all coupons. Try the below code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' , 'home_test_coupon_fix' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form' , 'home_test_coupon_fix' );

function home_test_coupon_fix() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $cart_total     = WC()->cart->get_subtotal();
    $minimum_amount = 500 + WC()->cart->get_coupon_discount_amount( $woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons[0] );
    $currency_code  = get_woocommerce_currency();
    wc_clear_notices();
    if ( $cart_total < $minimum_amount ) {
        WC()->cart->remove_coupon( $woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons[0] );
        wc_print_notice( "Get 50% off if you spend more than $minimum_amount $currency_code!", 'notice' );
    } 
    wc_clear_notices();
}
```

Comment: I think should br improvement a little bit + filter part

Comment: Does my answer help?

Comment: Yes, thank you. You give me right direction :)

Comment: Welcome... glad to be of help.